# Unable to select JNI build variant after upgrading Android Studio to version 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Java Android project that includes JNI code written in C.

I often need to debug into the native code and before upgrading Android Studio to version `3.3` it was working.

Now in my project view I don't have any code in my cpp folder. I have confirmed that all of the `C libraries` are in the folder on my HDD. The CMAKE file is also missing from the project view but is also in the correct place on my HDD.

I have not changed any code from my source control since upgrading.

I am using

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'.
```

In the Build Variants section next to my JNI module I just have five dashes instead of the debug/production options.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled android studio too.

Is it possible after upgrading I need to add something to my configuration to correct including CMAKE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, just figured it out.  In AndroidStudio 3.3.1, they changed things around a bit I guess.  Now you have to link your NDK build to the app you are building it as part of.

This is documented at: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds

The section, "Use the Android Studio UI" is what you want.